# Drupal 7 - Ajax dependent drop box and table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal

I have three dependent dropboxes , after select the option of third one, there will be a table generate and each row of the table has delete link am replacing all drop down list with the table content But the new drop down is losses the ajax functionality
 The regeneration code is as below

```
$form['ajax_fieldset'] = array(
                                    '#type' => 'fieldset',
                                    '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax_data_wrapper">',
                                    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);


$form['ajax_fieldset'] = array(
                                            '#type' => 'fieldset',
// These provide the wrapper referred to in #ajax['wrapper'] above.
                                            '#prefix' => '<div id="ajax_data_wrapper" style="">',
                                            '#suffix' => '</div>',
);


$form['ajax_fieldset']['country_select'] = array(
                      '#type' => 'select',
                      '#title' => t('Country List'),
                      '#options' => $countries_list,
                        '#ajax' => array(
                                    'wrapper' => 'ajax_data_wrapper',
                                    'callback' => 'get_country_select_callback',

),
);



$form['ajax_fieldset']['lang_select'] = array(
                      '#type' => 'select',
                      '#title' => t('Language List'),
                      '#options' => array(),
);



$form['ajax_fieldset']['audio_select'] = array(
                              '#type' => 'select',
                              '#title' => t('Audio List'),
                              '#options' => array(),
);


$table_data_1=table_creater($urls[2]);

$form['ajax_fieldset']['library_table']=$table_data_1;
$commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#ajax_data_wrapper",    render($form['ajax_fieldset']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to use `ajax_deliver()` method as follows,

```
 $commands = array();
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#selected_audio_wrapper", render($form['selected_audio_fieldset']));
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "call_from_ajax", array("") );
$page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($page);
```